# implement webstorage with observable in angular application

Tags: angular, local-storage, observable

I am using ngx-webstorage library in my angular application.
The problem is main component is already initialized when i call the `intitalizeIntro()`

I want to listen for changes in my local storage and execute  `introDashboard.start()`  method in main component.

This is what I have attempted.

child.component.ts

```
initializeIntro(value: string){
this.localStorage.store('selectedIntro', value); // value ='Dashboard'
console.log('Intro Activated ' + value); 
}
```

main.component.ts

```
ngOnChanges(){
this.localStorage.observe('selectedIntro') // i can see value stored in local storage
 .subscribe((newValue) =>{
   if(newValue === 'Dashboard'){ // but not able to enter if loop
     console.log('inside introDashboard loop');
     introDashboard.start();
   }
 });
}
```

Should i use some other lifecycle hook or how could i detect the change in local storage. If someone could provide explaination or point me towards material to check out, I would be glad.

I feel i should be using  `emit()`  somewhere but not able to understand how.

Answer (score 2):

can you try adding in ngOnInit method instead of ngOnchanges.

```
@LocalStorage('selectedIntro') boundAttribute;

ngOnInit(){
   this.localStorage.observe('selectedIntro') // i can see value stored in local storage
    .subscribe((newValue) =>{
    if(newValue === 'Dashboard'){ // but not able to enter if loop
     console.log('inside introDashboard loop');
     introDashboard.start();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It worked, but how can oninit() method be called multiple times, or is the subscribe method called within onInit() now listening for changes in localStorage variable?

Comment: Subscribe method in Rxjs is a data stream, which will emit stream of data and notify to subscribers. upvote so helpful to others.